# A tensor equation related to an invariant of a diffeomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra, multilinear-algebra

Let $M$ be an $n$-dimensional differentiable manifold, $f : U
\rightarrow V$ a diffeomorphism between open neighbourhoods $U$, $V$
of $M$ with $f(x)=x$ for some $x \in U$, and let $R$, $S$, $T$ be
tensor fields on $M$ of type $(p,q+1)$, $(p,q)$ and $(1,2)$ with $p+q
\geq 1$, respectively, such that
$$
  f^*S
  = S
$$
and
$$
  f^* R - R = \sum_{i=1}^{p} \mathrm{C}_{q+1}^{i} (S \otimes T) - \sum_{j=1}^{q} \mathrm{C}^{p+1}_j (S \otimes T)
$$
where $\mathrm{C}^i_j$ denotes the contraction with respect to the
$i$th contravariant index and the $j$th covariant index and $f^*$
denotes the pullback mapping induced by $f$.  Suppose also that $f^* R
- R$ does not vanish at any point of $U$.  Does it follow that there
exists a tensor field, say $Q$, on $M$ such that $f^* Q - Q = T$ on $U$
or is it possible to describe additional conditions on $S$ which are necessary / sufficient for such a
conclusion to hold?